# Error trapping in ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm following along in Ray's [The Complete Guide to Adding Error Handling to Your ColdFusion Application](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2007/12/5/The-Complete-Guide-to-Adding-Error-Handling-to-Your-ColdFusion-Application) and am intrigued by some of the values that are available, but I'm using the `onError` function in a scripted `Application.cfc`.

According to [learn.adobe.com](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cferror), cferror has a diagnostics error variable along with some other interesting bits like `error.remoteAddress` and `error.generatedContent`.

Q: If I am using onError in a [scripted Application.cfc](http://www.cutterscrossing.com/enclosures/Application.txt), then how do I get the diagnostics error variable (along with the others)?

Edit: Exactly how are you using `onError`?

```
public void function onSessionStart() {
    session.TryCatch = 3;
}

public boolean function onRequestStart(String targetPage){
    request.TickCount = GetTickCount();
    request.LogDBSort = 0;
    return true;
}

public void function onError(Exception,EventName) {
    if (StructKeyExists(session,"TryCatch") && session.TryCatch) {
        session.TryCatch -= 1;
        if (StructKeyExists(Exception,"Message")) {
            WriteOutput("It looks like you got the following ColdFusion error:<blockquote>"
                & Exception.Message
                & "</blockquote>"
            );
            local.LogCFErrMessage = Exception.Message;
        } else {
            local.LogCFErrMessage = "No Exception.Message";
        }
        param request.TickCount = GetTickCount();
        param request.LogDBSort = -999;
        request.LogDBSort += 1;

        if (StructKeyExists(Exception,"Name")) {
            local.LogCFErrName = Exception.Name;
        } else {
            local.LogCFErrName = "No Exception.Name";
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(Exception,"Detail")) {
            local.LogCFErrDetail = Exception.Detail;
        } else {
            local.LogCFErrDetail = "No Exception.Detail";
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(Exception,"Number")) {
            local.LogCFErrNumber = Exception.Number;
        } else {
            local.LogCFErrNumber = "No Exception.Number";
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(Exception,"Type")) {
            local.LogCFErrType = Exception.Type;
        } else {
            local.LogCFErrType = "No Exception.Type";
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(Exception,"EventName")) {
            local.LogCFErrEventName = Exception.EventName;
        } else {
            local.LogCFErrEventName = "No Exception.EventName";
        }
        local.svc = new query();
        local.sql = "
        DECLARE @LogCFErrSort Int = #Val(request.LogDBSort)#;
        DECLARE @LogCFErrNumber Int = #Val(local.LogCFErrNumber)#;
        DECLARE @LogCFErrElapsed Int = #GetTickCount() - request.TickCount#;
        INSERT INTO LogCFErr
        (LogCFErrSort, LogCFErrNumber, LogCFErrElapsed,LogCFErrName,LogCFErrDetail,LogCFErrMessage,LogCFErrType,LogCFErrEventName) VALUES(
        @LogCFErrSort,@LogCFErrNumber,@LogCFErrElapsed,?,?,?,?,?)
        ";
        local.svc.setSQL(local.sql);
        local.svc.addParam(cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR",value=Left(local.LogCFErrName,512));
        local.svc.addParam(cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR",value=Left(local.LogCFErrDetail,512));
        local.svc.addParam(cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR",value=Left(local.LogCFErrMessage,512));
        local.svc.addParam(cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR",value=Left(local.LogCFErrType,512));
        local.svc.addParam(cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR",value=Left(local.LogCFErrEventName,512));
        local.svc.execute();
        if (IsDefined("Application.Home.Email.UserName")) {
            local.svc = new mail();
            local.svc.setSubject(GetApplicationMetaData().Name & ': ' & ListLast(GetBaseTemplatePath(),'\'));
            local.msg = LogCFErrMessage;
            local.svc.setBody(local.msg);

            local.svc.setServer(Application.Home.Email.Server);
            local.svc.setType(Application.Home.Email.Type);
            local.svc.setUseSSL(Application.Home.Email.UseSSL);
            local.svc.setPort(Application.Home.Email.Port);
            local.svc.setFrom(Application.Home.Email.UserName);
            local.svc.setUserName(Application.Home.Email.UserName);
            local.svc.setPassword(Application.Home.Email.Password);
            local.svc.setTo(Application.Home.Email.UserName);
            local.svc.Send();
            WriteOutput("I've sent an email to the administrator to let them know.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly how are you using onError?

Comment: (Edit - I do not have time to write up an answer but ...) Most of those values (remote address, etcetera) are simple request parameters which [can be obtained several ways, such as via GetHTTPRequestData(), CGI scope, etcetera](http://www.stephenwithington.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/8/26/CGI-Variables-and-Their-Respective-ColdFusionJava-Servlet-Alternative-Methods). I believe "message" is similar to "diagnostics", just minus the line number, which can be obtained from `Error.TagContent.Line`.

Comment: I double checked the docs for `onError` and `cfcatch` which seem to confirm `arguments.Exception.message` is basically `Diagnostics` (again, just minus the error line number): [*cfcatch.message` - Message: Exception's diagnostic message ..*](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfcatch). So it seems like most of the information is still available via `exception`, or from the request data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use arguments.exception.  Here is an example.

```
<cffunction name="onError">
<cfargument name="Exception" required=true type="any">
 more code

<cfmail to="#recipients#" 
from="#recipients#" 
subject="Error on whatever" type="html">

<p>Error Occurred #now()#</p> 
<cfdump var="#Arguments.Exception#" label="exception">
<cfdump var="#request#" label="request">
<cfdump var="#cgi#" label="cgi">
</cfmail>
```